# What is a good web browser for OS X 10.4 Tiger?

Tags: software-recommendation, web-browsing, macos

I have an old MacBook that can't run anything higher than 10.4, due to hardware limitations.

Is there any decent modern browser I can run?  Opera, Safari and Firefox all need at least 10.6.

I just want websites to work correctly. I am aware that there are security issues and that I should not be running such old software in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TenFourFox](http://www.floodgap.com/software/tenfourfox/) gives you the current version of Firefox in builds optimized for G3, G4 and G5 PowerPC processors that runs on Mac OS 10.4 and 10.5.

[image: TenFourFox]

Comment: As of April 2017, [TenFourFox](http://www.floodgap.com/software/tenfourfox/) is the only web browser still being developed for OS X 10.4 Tiger, thanks to the indefatigable Cameron Kaiser. Due to security issues, it is the _only_ browser that anyone running Tiger should be using to browse the web.

Comment: [Development of TenFourFox has halted](http://www.floodgap.com/software/tenfourfox/) but it can downloaded and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [camino](http://caminobrowser.org/), which requires Mac OS X 10.4 or later. Just nice for you.

Their webpage says they are no longer supporting it though:

> After a decade-long run, Camino is no longer being developed, and we encourage all users to upgrade to a more modern browser. Camino is increasingly lagging behind the fast pace of changes on the web, and more importantly it is not receiving security updates, making it increasingly unsafe to use.

Answer (score 0):

I was always a big fan of [OmniWeb](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omniweb/) back in the day. I even paid for it before charging money for a browser was a completely archaic concept. It runs on 10.4.8 or later.

Comment: I am the same, I am a fan of omniweb and think that it is a good browser, but tenfour fox is good as well but be warned that you wont be able to use flash videos or games.