# How can I update SSL certificates on macOS Tiger?

Tags: macos, safari, security, keychain, ssl

I Want to update ssl certificates on my iMac G4, macOS Tiger (10.4.11).
I already tried to copy from a newer mac the certificate "Actalis Authentication Root CA", trust in in Keychain Access but when with safari i go on the website "alternativalinux.it" i recive the error "**Safari cannot enstabilish a safe connection with alternativalinux.com**".

Comment: Certificates are going to be only the first of your issues - next will come your SSL & TLS being incompatible with modern sites. I think Mavericks 10.9 is about the oldest OS that can deal with modern sites using TLS 1.2.

Comment: Not sure whether the answers to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47122/what-is-a-good-web-browser-for-os-x-10-4-tiger are still valid, but worth trying.

Comment: Also https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/894856

Comment: I already know ten four fox but I want to use Safari

Comment: alternativalinux.com is a non-active website, I can't securely connect with any browser. Do you have the problem only with that site, or also with others?

Comment: @nohillside - I have no problem connecting to the fist address the OP posted - resolves to https://www.alternativalinux.it

Comment: @Tetsujin Indeed. [That site requires TLS1.2](https://observatory.mozilla.org/analyze/www.alternativalinux.it#tls) which seems to be only availabe from Safari 5 onwards. Tiger runs Safari 4.x as far as I know. Paolo, can you check the Safari version you are running?

Comment: The problem that i have when i try to connect to some websites like alternativalinux.it is that safari tell me "Unsafe website" and don't load the page

Comment: Did you check which version of Safari you are running on your Tiger Mac?

Comment: Safari 4. The default tiger version

Answer (score 1):

According to https://observatory.mozilla.org/analyze/www.alternativalinux.it#tls, the site requires TLS 1.2 and Safari 5. I didn‘t find a technical documentation for Safari 4 but assume that it doesn‘t support TLS 1.2. TLS 1.2 needs code to handle it, a simple certificate update will not help here.

So you can‘t use Safari 4 any longer to connect to modern web pages.

Comment: I've updated to Leopard. Can I update ssl cerificates now? I Have safari 5 too